# YUI - get node from 'this' keyword

Tags: dom, select, yui

How can I select YUI node with this keyword?

Example:

```
<a href='javascript:test(this);'>Click Me!</a>

<script>
    function test(el){
        YUI().use('transition', function (Y) {
            var selectedElement = Y.one(el);
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, "this" will refer to the Window object, not the link.  A better way to do this in YUI is:

```
<a href="#" id="my-link">Click Me!</a>
<script>
YUI().use('transition', function(Y) {
  Y.one('#my-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.halt();
    var selectedElement = e.target;
  });
});
</script>
```

This avoid JavaScript embedded in the markup, which is considered best practice.  Also, it wraps all your code in the YUI sandbox, which is the recommended way.